# Not able to use base64 encoded data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, ocr, google-vision

So i have this code which uses a base_64 encoded data(image data) , converts it into an image and runs google vision (OCR) on it . But there is some issue with the base_64 encoded data . Even thought it is correct it throws the following error .

> Invalid base64 encoded string: number of data characters (167737) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Since that string is 2000 lines i cannot input it here , `b'/9j/4af..........TE2f//Z'` this is how it starts and ends and has 167737 characters in it.
So what do i do now as im not able to convert it back to image file . And just to test the code i am using an image which i converted to base_64 and using that string to pass it to a different code which is supposed to give me the text output after running ocr on the converted image.

Comment: How did you convert the image to base64? It seems the conversion is not being done properly.

Comment: I used my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read()) , i dont think there is an issue with the conversion

Comment: You say "even though it is correct" but it clearly isn't: the error message is telling you exactly what is wrong. Base-64 strings are always a multiple of 4 characters. It may be that you have inadvertently added a character on the end (a line-feed, maybe, that would be hard to see in an editor). First thing to try is making sure your string isn't too long.

Comment: maybe google insists on padding (the number of encoded chars must be dividable by 3, if not you have to add padding chars '=').

Comment: Alright ,ill try it out once , you guys are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing padding.

```
padding = len(data) % 4
if padding > 0:
    data += b'='* (4 - padding)
base64.b64decode(data)
```