# Why While Update Django base64 imagefile upload error Invalid base64-encode string?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hey I use the base64 function to upload image in the Django server when I tried to use `POST` method to add upload image its work fine frontend side but when I tried to update and use the `PUT` method the image is through the error `invalid nbas64-encoded string: a number of data character can not be 1 more than a multiple of 4` So how to resolve this, Here is my base64 code.

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')
                ext = format.split('/')[-1] 
            try:
                # data = data.partition(",")[2]
                decoded_file = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                    data + '=' * (-len(data) % 4))
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)
            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )
            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

        return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr
        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension
        return extension
```

and i use like this field of image.

```
class CarPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    file = Base64ImageField(
        max_length=None,
        use_url=True,
        required=False,
        allow_null=True,
        allow_empty_file=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that your base64 encoding is incorrect. The encoding stream converts every 3 inputs bytes to 4 ASCII characters and your error suggests that your input must be malformed, i.e. it's trying to decode something that's not a multiple of 3 bytes.

To identify if this is just a Django related error, try the steps [here](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/convert-image-to-string-in-python/) to ensure that the image can be encoded in base 64. You should also try to run this in an `incognito` mode to ensure that there's no presence of session cookies interference. You can even attempt to clear your cookies if it helps.

Have you also taken into account of `padding`? This may help - [Not able to use base64 encoded data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050993/not-able-to-use-base64-encoded-data-in-pyhton)